# Access previous page controls value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback, postbackurl

i have a problem i want to access controls of previous pages values. I know that i can use postbackurl but i must use OnClientClick property because i must call javascript method and according to the criterias my url change. Below method is called OnClientClick property. This page name Calculator.aspx

```
        function redirectSellPage() {

        var type = getParameterByName('type');


        if (type == 'test') {
            window.location.href = "Change.aspx?PageType=a";
        } else if (a == null || a == "") {
            window.location.href = "Change.aspx?PageType=b";
        } else {
            window.location.href = "Change.aspx?PageType=c";
        }


    }
```

I want to access Calculator.aspx controls values in Change.aspx.
How can i do that.

Comment: Why dont you attach the values of Calculator.aspx controls to the URL?

Comment: You can use dopostbackwithoptions instead of setting window.location.href=url.
Or you can set form.action to url and do form.submit.
In that case you can acesss previous page controls using Request.Form["name"].

Answer (score 0):

In source page, which in your case is Calculator.aspx, add this:

```
public String Value1
{
get
{
    return YourTextBoxId.Text;
}
}
```

On the target page, which in your case is Change.aspx, add a @ PreviousPageType page directive that points to the source page.

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Calculator.aspx" %>
```

Now in target page use PreviousPage property to access values.

```
String val = PreviousPage.Value1;
```